# CLI based file manager that shows tree-like directory extructure

Tags: command-line, filemanager

If you have the program "tree" installed on your system and you happen to run this the command

```
tree
```

in your system, the result is something like this:

```
├── a
├── b
└── c
    ├── a
    ├── b
    └── c

6 directories, 0 files
```

I am looking for a file manager that works exactly like this, but I need to be able to use my mouse with it, just like a regular GUI file manager.

is there such program in existence?

I want to click on the file names , folder names, rather than an icon of a folder or a file.

Answer (score 5):

midnight commander - a GNU project is what you want.  It is text based tree browsing with use of the mouse.  You can `apt-get install mc` or get it from the Ubuntu Software Center. [Midnight Commander GNU page](http://www.midnight-commander.org/)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

When using arch linux I remember using Ranger. You could try that out.

Comment: Ranger won't work with the mouse, it is Terminal only. From the question: 'but I need to be able to use my mouse with it'. Do you know of any others?

Comment: Ranger works with the mouse

Answer (score 1):

Micro Editor in terminal has tree too:
https://micro-editor.github.io

Install File Manager extension to it and show tree view for file browsing:
https://micro-editor.github.io/plugins.html

```
micro -plugin install filemanager
```